# Does it possible customize the pin event of Map to reduce tap times

Tags: forms, dictionary, xamarin, events

After Xamarin Form Map shows a map on an Android or iOS device, and tap a map pin, it will show the callout of the pin and tap this callout, it just triggers the pin's clicked event, i.e., two tap actions are required to trigger the pin event. Is it possible let Xamarin Form Map to trigger an event which can do something when tap the pin, i.e., one tap action can trigger an event which is associated the tapped pin by rendering Xamarin Map (for both Android and iOS)? If so, how to do it?

The link doesn't give any detail hint for my question
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin

Comment: Do you want to touch the pin and to do something like show detail adress info?

Comment: Here is Tapping on the map to get the relative location (to put a new pin, to get the relative address).If be helpful,let me know.(https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.com/2015/08/xamarinformsmaps-tap-to-get-position-on.html)

Comment: I have a StackLayout which has some buttons, Lables, etc. I want to show it on the map after a pin is tapped. Please help me. Thanks